# How to make one layer different roughness than another one procedurally?

Tags: procedural

So this my object:

[image]

I want the YELLOW STRIPES to have zero roughness and the metalic grey cube to have a higher Roughness, how can I control that?

Here is the node Tree:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried writing this several times with only words, but it became a bit complicated. Instead, here's an example that I think is closer to how your graph *should* look (everything is subjective), see if you can follow what I did differently.

[image: MixA]

The main difference is that on your graph, you have 3 Mix Shaders mixing a shader with nothing, as well as a "Wave Texture Mask", placed on the "wrong" mix shader.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

NOTE - I made the metallic part of mine extra shiny just to show the difference in roughness values. Also note that due to the transparency, if using Alpha-Blend as a blend mode, you may need to disable "Show Backface".

Comment: Sorry, I missed that your mapping nodes had scale values set - I thought they were default so I removed them in my graph. Feel free to add them in where applicable.